# Postgres ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE all fields

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a database in which the primary key of a record is a string, its name

Desire: if a new record is presented that matches the name of an old record, update all fields other than the name. What didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO playlists (name, filter, selection, clips)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
```

this gets a syntax error. It wants me to put something after DO UPDATE, but when I mean "update all fields to the new VALUES", how do I say it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
... ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET(name, filter, selection, clips) = ROW(excluded.*)
```